# Why is volatile required with template argument in one case but not other?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, volatile

In C++03, I have the following code built with gcc v3.4.6 for which I don't understand why calling `_setValueSafeFails()` get a compiler error where as calling the similar `_incrValueSafe()` does not.

Test.h:

```
class Test
{
public:
  void test();

  template<typename T> void _incrValueSafe(T &value) {
    ++value;
  }

  template<typename T> void _setValueSafeFails(T &value, const T setVal) {
    value = setVal;
  }

  template<typename T> void _setValueSafeWorks(volatile T &value, const T setVal) {
    value = setVal;
  }

  volatile bool _testValue;

};
```

Test.cpp:

```
#include "Test.h"

void Test::test() {
  _incrValueSafe(_testValue);
  _setValueSafeFails(_testValue, true);
  _setValueSafeWorks(_testValue, true);
}

Test.cpp: In member function `void Test::test()':
Test.cpp:5: error: no matching function for call to `Test::_setValueSafeFails(volatile bool&, bool)'
```

Shouldn't `_incrValueSafe()` get the same error since there is no `volatile` in its signature either?  How are these two treated differently, or is this just a compiler bug?

Comment: (has nothing to do with your question, but you shouldn't lead your variable names with _, those are reserved symbols)

Comment: I thought it was double underscore that was reserved, but these are inside a class, so should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have explained, binding the first parameter to `_testValue` implies
that `T` is `volatile bool`, whereas binding the second parameter to `true`
implies that `T` is merely `bool` (without the `volatile` modifier).  The
`clang` compiler gives a nice diagnostic:

```
clang++ -o main  -std=c++1y -pedantic -Wall -stdlib=libc++ main.cpp -stdlib=libc++
main.cpp:26:5: error: no matching member function for call to '_setValueSafeFails'
    _setValueSafeFails(_testValue, true);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:12:35: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('volatile bool' vs. 'bool')
        template<typename T> void _setValueSafeFails(T &value, const T setVal) {
                                  ^
main.cpp:9:13: warning: incrementing expression of type bool is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-increment-bool]
            ++value;
            ^ ~~~~~
main.cpp:25:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Test::_incrValueSafe<volatile bool>' requested here
    _incrValueSafe(_testValue);
    ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Regarding leading underscores: I just avoid them, partly to avoid debates about
what is or isn't strictly legal.  I prefer the popular convention: prefix
private variables with `m_`, and don't decorate private function names in any
special way.  (Leading underscores are de rigeur for private members in Python,
but of course, C++ is a very different language.) For the record, the holy
standard says the following:

> `17.6.4.3.2 Global names [global.names]`
>
> ---
>
> 1. Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the
>       implementation:
>
>    — Each name that contains a double underscore `__` or begins with an
>          underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.12) is reserved to the
>          implementation for any use.
>
>    — Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the
>          implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

`typename T` for `_incrValueSafe` is `volatile bool`

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
template<typename T> void _setValueSafeFails(T &value, const T setVal) {
    value = setVal;
}
```

would be instanciated to:

```
void _setValueSafeFails(volatile bool &value, const volatile bool setVal)
```

Answer (score 0):

The type volatile bool and bool are different types and lead to the mismatch in _setValueSafeFails.

You may do:

```
class Test
{
public:
  void test();
  template<typename T, typename U> void _setValueSafeA(T &value, const U setVal) {
    value = setVal;
  }
  template<typename T> void _setValueSafeB(T &value, const T& setVal) {
    value = setVal;
  }

  volatile bool _testValue;

};

void Test::test() {
  volatile bool true_value = true;
  _setValueSafeA(_testValue, true);
  _setValueSafeB(_testValue, true_value);
}
```